# Empty cells with math.isnan()

Tags: python

I have to check if cells in a column of a data frame are empty with math.isnan() . If not, they must display the given values again. Others they must “empty”.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear but perhaps something like this:

```
new = None if math.isnan(val) else val
```

Comment: My english isn’t that good sorry. Can you perhaps explain what the math.isnan() functies actually does?

Comment: No worries! Math.isnan() takes a value as an input and determines if it is a number. If the value is a number, it returns False; if it isn't it returns True.

Comment: For example, if you took math.isnan(3), it would return False, because 3 is a number. Math.isnan(math.nan) would return True, because math.nan is undefined